# Pivot Table in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to count all the ID's that are unique to A,B,C,D. So 
"A"/"A" , "B"/"B","C"/"C", "D"/"D" - should give me count of ID unique to A,B,C,D.
Whereas "A"/"B" and  "B"/"A"- will be ID which have Place as A and B. Similarly "A"/"C" and "C"/"A"  = will be ID which have Place as A and C. The ID's overlap across the two places.The count needs to keep on incrementing with each overlap Please can someone suggest. I have a table as below

```
ID     Place
1       A
2       B
1       C
6       B
4       D
5       A
6       C
7       A
8       A
8       C
```

Can you please guide me to come up with following output

```
   A B C D
A  2 0 2 0
B  0 1 1 0
C  2 1 0 0
D  0 0 0 1
```

Comment: You should explain the logic of building that matrix! otherwise you most likely to get more downvotes and most importantly have no chance to get help from us - so please edit your question with more details

Comment: I Apologize for that. Logic :- "A"/"A" , "B"/"B","C"/"C", "D"/"D" - should give me count of ID unique to A,B,C,D. Whereas "A"/"B" - will be ID which have Place as A and B. Similarly "A"/"C" =  will be ID which have Place as A and C. The ID's overlap across the two places.

Comment: makes total sense now  - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH self AS (
  SELECT arr[OFFSET(0)] place, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(place) arr, id
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) = 1
  )
  GROUP BY place
), pairs AS (
  SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(place) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY id
), flat_matrix AS (
  SELECT place1, place2, COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
  FROM pairs, UNNEST(arr) place1, UNNEST(arr) place2
  WHERE place1 <> place2
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT place, place, cnt
  FROM self
)
SELECT place1 place,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'A', cnt, 0)) AS A,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'B', cnt, 0)) AS B,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'C', cnt, 0)) AS C,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'D', cnt, 0)) AS D 
FROM flat_matrix
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'A' place UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'C'   
), self AS (
  SELECT arr[OFFSET(0)] place, COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(place) arr, id
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) = 1
  )
  GROUP BY place
), pairs AS (
  SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(place) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY id
), flat_matrix AS (
  SELECT place1, place2, COUNT(DISTINCT id) cnt
  FROM pairs, UNNEST(arr) place1, UNNEST(arr) place2
  WHERE place1 <> place2
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT place, place, cnt
  FROM self
)
SELECT place1 place,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'A', cnt, 0)) AS A,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'B', cnt, 0)) AS B,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'C', cnt, 0)) AS C,
  MAX(IF(place2 = 'D', cnt, 0)) AS D 
FROM flat_matrix
GROUP BY place1
-- ORDER BY place
```

with result as

```
Row place   A   B   C   D    
1   A       2   0   2   0    
2   B       0   1   1   0    
3   C       2   1   0   0    
4   D       0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail. This really helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you basically want:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select t.place,
       max(case when t2.place = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       max(case when t2.place = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
       max(case when t2.place = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
       max(case when t2.place = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D
from t join
     t t2
     on t.id = t2.id and t.seqnum <> t2.seqnum
group by t.place
order by t.place;
```

This is not exactly the output you have in the question, but it seems to handle the overlaps logically.  I don't see how you have "A"/"A" with 1 but "C"/"C" with 0.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I will try it.  "A"/"A"  is zero because there is just one ID unique to A i.e is ID =5 the other ID is shared with C. Also "C"/"C" is zero because there is no ID just unique to C, it is shared with A and B.